# Geometry is wrong for UV Mapping?

Tags: materials, uv, geometry

I would like to ask your help regarding with my problem. I was following a tutorial on how to create a realistic bread and I cannot really figure out why the slice looks smudged and blurred, after trying to use quadrats as geometry and using a separate UV map and material for the slice.

Does anyone have a tip how to fix that? Thanks a lot in advance! :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Here](https://we.tl/t-uDJNntEYjg) is the blender file I was making and the maps that I used, provided by blenderguru. :)

Comment: Hello, it would help if you showed the UV map  ;)  maybe even share your file (after packing the images)

Comment: @moonboots thanks for the help! I uploaded the blender file and the maps that I used as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the *Properties* panel > *Object Data > UV Maps*, you need to activate the UV map you want to use, which is supposed to be *Slice*:

[image]

Comment: Omg! Thanks a lot! You really helped me out! :)